# Excel: Run cell's content as command in cmd when pressing a button

Tags: excel, vba

I am not too familiar with VBScripts and Macros, but I hope someone can help me out.

I have a sheet with around 300 lines. Each line defines a testcase and in the last row there's a command that I have to copy to clipboard and then paste it in a command line window to run the test.
I was wondering if it's possible to but a button in `B1, B2, B3` etc that automatically runs the command in `C1, C2, C3` etc. in a cmd window.

Can this be done?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Shell Sheet1.Range("C1"), vbNormalFocus
End Sub
```